# Is there a way I can override values of two tables while joining them together, adding columns if needed?

Tags: mysql

**Question**: How can I can override values of two tables while joining them together, adding columns if needed?

**Logic**

1. Merge two tables based on product_id. (table 1 as a base, table 2 as a sub (inherits from base))
2. Does table 2 have columns from table 1?

   1. Yes

      1. override values from table 1 with values from table 2.
   2. No

      1. Add column to merged table.

*Here is a simple structure of the tables I'm working with.*

**Base Products (table 1)**

```
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
| id | product_id | name      | price |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | p190x4     | Product 1 |    50 |
|  2 | px180i     | Product 2 |    50 |
|  3 | zz9980     | Product 3 |    50 |
|  4 | zz9212     | Product 4 |    50 |
|  5 | tu8uii     | Product 5 |    50 |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
```

**Sub Products (table 2)**

```
+----+------------+-------+----------+
| id | product_id | price | location |
+----+------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | p190x4     |    34 | NA       |
|  2 | px180i     |    17 | RU       |
|  4 | zz9212     |    65 | LA       |
+----+------------+-------+----------+
```

**Wanted Results**

```
+----+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
| id | product_id | name      | price | location |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
|  1 | p190x4     | Product 1 | 34    | NA       |
|  2 | px180i     | Product 2 | 17    | RU       |
|  4 | zz9212     | Product 4 | 65    | LA       |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
```

In the wanted results you can see a couple things have happened.

1. The `name` column was `added` from table 1.
2. The `location` column was `added` from table 2.
3. The `price` column was `updated` using values from table 2, rather than table 1.

**EDIT**

The column names are dynamic. The sub products table needs to be flexible where I can easily add a property (column) or remove a property (column).

Comment: To clarify - you co _not_ know the table definitions of either table ahead of time?

Comment: This is just an ordinary join, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I can join the values together, but the problem with just joining them is that I cannot figure out how to override the value from table 1 with value from table 2. It will keep appending numbers to the end of the column where as I just need it to overwrite that column.

Comment: Usually one simply specifies in the `SELECT` list which columns one wishes to retrieve (using table qualifiers as necessary in the event of name collisions).

Comment: If the columns are dynamic, how do you know which ones should come from `Products` and which should be overridden from `Sub Products`?

Comment: @barmar That's kind of where I'm stuck. I'm thinking of this like inheritance. Table 2 inherits from table 1, overriding any of the columns in table 1.

Comment: does this have to be done entirely in SQL, or can we use a language with arrays, like PHP?

Comment: If it has to be done in SQL, you need to generate dynamic SQL using the `information_schema.columns` table.

Comment: @barmar Sorry I had a typo with the id (which is a foreign key)(if that was the confusion there.) Yes, it has to be done in SQL. I'll take a look at `information_schema.columns table`. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Search SO for the `[dynamic-sql]` tag to find examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one simply specifies in the SELECT list which columns one wishes to retrieve (using table qualifiers as necessary in the event of name collisions):

```
SELECT t1.id, product_id, t1.name, t2.price, t2.location
FROM   t1 JOIN t2 USING (product_id);
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d7b4/3/0).

If the schema is not known ahead of time, one can dynamically construct the requisite SQL from the information schema.  For example, doing the whole thing within MySQL (which wouldn't be my first choice, but since you have not specified the language or API in which your application is developed it will suffice to show the general principle):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  -- the SQL that we are constructing for subsequent execution
  ' SELECT ',GROUP_CONCAT(
              '`',REPLACE(t,'`','``'),'`.`',REPLACE(c,'`','``'),'`'
              ORDER BY t, p
             ),
  ' FROM   t1 JOIN t2 USING (product_id)'
) INTO @sql FROM (
  -- the table-qualified column references that we wish to select
  SELECT   MAX(TABLE_NAME)  t,  -- MAX because 't2'>'t1'
           COLUMN_NAME      c,
           ORDINAL_POSITION p
  FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE    TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
       AND TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t2')
  GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
) t;

-- prepare the statement for execution
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

-- execute it
EXECUTE stmt;

-- tidy up
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET @sql := NULL;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d7b4/3/3).

Comment: Oh wow, this seems to be a lot more complicated than I imagined. At least complicated to me. This works awesome, but after some thought, I may be structuring the db the incorrect way. I'll have to go back to the drawing board. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases and qualify fields you want to ouptut :

```
SELECT s.id, p.product_id AS product_id, p.name , s.price AS price , s.location
FROM product p
INNER JOIN sub_product s ON (s.product_id = p.product_id)
```

**updated** (`product_id` instead of `id`)

Comment: You're not joining on the correct columns. `p.id` should be `p.product_id`.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, fixing... I got confused by `id` columns.